# Bash syntax errors: operand expected with arithmetic operations

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am constructing a script to count the occurrences of two letters in a given string. I cannot figure out how to make the variable a testable number.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch ~/trfindlog.txt ~/trfindt ~/trfindr
echo $1 > ~/trfindlog.txt

cat ~/trfindlog.txt | grep -oi r | wc -l > ~/trfindr

cat ~/trfindlog.txt | grep -oi t | wc -l > ~/trfindt

varR='/trfindr'
varT='/trfindt'

if [[ "${varR}" -eq 0 && "${varT}" -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains no Rs or Ts."

elif [[ "${varR}" -eq 1 && "${varT}" -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains 1 R and 1 T."

elif [[ "${varR}" -gt 1 && "${varT}" -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains ${varR} Rs and 1 T."

elif [[ "${varR}" -eq 1 && "${varT}" -gt 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains 1 R and ${varT} Ts."

elif [[ "${varR}" -gt 1 && "${varT}" -gt 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains ${varR} Rs and ${varT} Ts."

fi

rm ~/trfindlog.txt ~/trfindt ~/trfindr

exit
```

This script is giving me the following errors.

> /automount/home/jcampbell/tools/itc/trfind.sh: line 12: [[: /trfindr: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/trfindr")
>
> /automount/home/jcampbell/tools/itc/trfind.sh: line 16: [[: /trfindr: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/trfindr")
>
> /automount/home/jcampbell/tools/itc/trfind.sh: line 20: [[: /trfindr: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/trfindr")
>
> /automount/home/jcampbell/tools/itc/trfind.sh: line 24: [[: /trfindr: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/trfindr")
>
> /automount/home/jcampbell/tools/itc/trfind.sh: line 28: [[: /trfindr: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/trfindr")

Here is the working script. This is just for kicks & educating myself. I am glad to receive a variety of answers.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch ~/trfindlog.txt
echo $1 > ~/trfindlog.txt

varR=$(echo $1 | tr -cd r)
varT=$(echo $1 | tr -cd t)

if [[ "${#varR}" -eq 0 && "${#varT}" -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains no Rs or Ts."

elif [[ "${#varR}" -eq 1 && "${#varT}" -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains 1 R and 1 T."

elif [[ "${#varR}" -gt 1 && "${#varT}" -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains ${#varR} Rs and 1 T."

elif [[ "${#varR}" -eq 1 && "${#varT}" -gt 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains 1 R and ${#varT} Ts."

elif [[ "${#varR}" -gt 1 && "${#varT}" -gt 1 ]]
then
    echo "This phrase contains ${#varR} Rs and ${#varT} Ts."

fi

rm ~/trfindlog.txt

exit
```

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are assigning the file name, not its contents, to the variables you get errors for.

Comment: In case it's not familiar, you can get the result in a variable like `rcount=$(grep -oi 'r' <<<"$1" | wc -l)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like

```
var=$(grep -c r ~/trfindlog.txt)
```

Note that `grep` will count the number of matching lines, and not the number of matches. So, what you really need is more something like:

```
var=$(echo $1 | tr -cd r)
echo ${#var}
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting the variable in a file is cumbersome, inelegant, and, with a static filename, will break if you run two instances of the script at the same time.  All of this would be a lot more succinct with the variable in memory.

With Bash, you can make a copy of the variable and perform a simple substitution.

```
Rs=${1//[!R]/}
Ts=${1//[!T]/}
```

Now, the length of each of these strings is the number of occurrences of the characters you were looking for.

```
echo "We have ${#Rs} R characters and ${#Ts} T characters."
```

Deciding whether to print a plural `s` should be a simple addition.  Hint: If the first string is exactly `R` you want to suppress the `s`.  But if you want flexible wording, it may be simpler to use a `case` statement over the possibilities.

```
case $Rs:$Ts in
    :)   echo "We have none of either";;
    R:)  echo "We have one R and no Ts.";;
    :T)  echo "We have no Rs and one T.";;
    R:T) echo "We have one of each.";;
    *:)  echo "We have ${#Rs} Rs and no Ts.";;
    *:T) echo "We have ${#Rs} Rs and one T.";;
    :*)  echo "We have no Rs and ${#Ts} Ts.";;
    R:*) echo "We have one R and ${#Ts} Ts.";;
    *:*) echo "We have ${#Rs} and ${#Ts} Ts.";;
esac
```

I would still be tempted to handle the cornermost cases `:` and `R:T` as above, and then generate a string from smaller pieces in the remaining cases.

Comment: I used uppercase instead of lower and am too lazy to change it.